# how to merge two files into one file in Unix bash?

Tags: bash, unix, merge

i have two files:

```
filea          fileb
apple          juice
orange         pieces
pineapple      juice
```

I want to store in a new file the output

```
applejuice
orangepieces
pineapplejuice
```

meaning concatenate the 2 files in unix bash
i tried `paste filea.txt fileb.txt > new.txt` but i had an error is there another option? thank you

Comment: I'd normally use something like paste. What error did you get ?

Comment: Just a nit-pick, concatenate means something else entirely. You should reword the question.

Comment: What was the exact error message you got with paste? That's the command to use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by error while invoking `paste` but you probably wanted to specify the delimiter:

```
paste -d '' filea fileb > new.txt
```

This would yield:

```
applejuice
orangepieces
pineapplejuice
```

Comment: i found this online : nawk 'NR==FNR{_[NR]=$0;next}{print $1,$2,_[FNR]}' fileb filea    and it worked

Comment: yet I don't really understand the syntax . One more thing I'm getting spaces between filea and fileb , and I don't want to get any spaces meaning i want applejuice not apple juice. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `man paste` is your friend.  If you're getting spaces in between the words, that would be because your input file contains extra space after the string (e.g. "apple" would actually be "apple " in the original file).  You can pipe the output to `tr -d [:space:]` in order to eliminate the spaces.